# How to select text character by character with shift and directions?

Tags: visual-mode

I would like to know how I can select text character by character, in visual mode, using a combination of shift+direction without using the mouse.
Actually, with Shit + Left/Right gvim selects the text word by word.

For example, in the following screenshot, I am able to select the text **std::cout** using the mouse, left button click on the start of text and then shifting the mouse cursor to the right.

[image]

How can I replicate this behavior with just using the keyboard ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**short answer:**

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> selects `std::cout`

If you really want to select character by character, just

<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>h</kbd> / <kbd>l</kbd>

**long answer:**

<kbd>v</kbd> enters [visual mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html)

<kbd>W</kbd> [motion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html) to select [WORD](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#W)

If you really want to select character by character, just

<kbd>v</kbd>  enters visual mode

<kbd>h</kbd> / <kbd>l</kbd> [motion by character](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_02.html#02.3)

(The answer assumes, that you are not using any plugins and that they do not define additional motions)

[Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org) has excellent videos, that basically explain everything.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I can do it using shift key with some combination ooff direction keys rather than pressing ESC and v, but it doesn't work.